# Как лучше строить взаимодействие с базой данных

Tags: java, база-данных, dao

Спрошу сразу на примере. Предположим у нас есть POJO `Person`, например такой:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_TBL")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    private String mail;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String secondName;

    public Person(){
    }

    //Getters & Setters 
}
```

В данном случае взаимодействие с БД построено на основе аннотаций JPA. Дальше добавляю таблицу сообщений и создаю класс сообщений:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGES_TBL")
public class Message  { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private Person sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipient_id")
    private Person recipient;

    private String messageText;

    publik Message(){
    }

    //getters & setters
}
```

Дальше у меня есть два варианта: Добавить в класс `Person` поле `List<Message> messages;` и не создавать дополнительный DAO слой для работы с сообщениями, работая с сообщениями через `Person`(например для добавления сообщения добавить его в `List` сообщений и сохранить сущность) или создать DAO и работать с таблице сообщений напрямую. Как лучше или вообще без разницы?

Answer (score 1):

Создав поле в классе, тебе придется работать через инстанс этого класса. Либо можно создать отдельный компонент, через который работать с базой откуда угодно и не привязываясь к инстансу какого-то класса. Тут надо смотреть на то, как ты хочешь в дальнейшем этим пользоваться.